# Import single macro from file

Tags: macros, input

I have an automatically generated .tex file containing some content and a couple, usually just one, `\newcommand` calls.

Usually I display the content and load the commands with `\input` but sometimes I'd like to just import the commands it defines without displaying anything.

Is there an easy way to achieve it?

**EDIT:** Here's a little example of what I'd like to do:

**`table.tex:`**

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
  \hline%
  foo & bar \\
  bar & foo \\
  \hline%
\end{tabular}
\newcommand\tabledata{This is a foo table about bars}
```

**`mwe.tex:`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \input{table.tex}
  \caption{About this table: \emph{\tabledata}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Sometimes I'd like to not display the table but just `\tabledata` while keeping the normal `\input` behavior working. Also I'd like to keep the `\tabledata` local but I could do fine with `\renewcommand`.

I sometimes call `\tabledata` inside a secondary `\ContinuedFloat\caption`, but let's not get too specific about my case.

Comment: It's usually better to split content and macros. Macros should in most cases be in packages or in the preamble, not somewhere in between

Comment: if the content does not change the main file strecture you can use a save box

Comment: @touhami: Isn't the macro definition done in the box then too, captured for all time?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer we want to skip text and have the command defined. it's the first and the easiest idea that come to me.

Comment: @touhami: I don't get you. I think you want to `\input` the stuff into a box, regardless what's in the input file?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes that is :`\setbox0=\hbox{\let\def\gdef\input{file}}`

Comment: @touhami: And how do get the defined macros from the file out of the box then???? The content is hidden, that's for sure

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not sure i understand what you mean. if `\mycommand` is defined in `file.tex` you can type `\mycommand` anywhere after `\setbox0=\hbox{\let\def\gdef\input{file}}` But you know that so as you said `we have a different understanding of the question`

Comment: @touhami: thanks, seems promising and think you got the question, but I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`, probably should come up with some MWE

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Actually the macro in this case is content too, the tex file contains a tabular environment and a macro defining some metadata about the table that I display after the main caption (in a `\ContinuedFloat` secondary caption). Sometimes I need to display just that metadata and no table.

Comment: @filippo: That's content that is expanded later on, but is not typeset directly as you would write something like `In this foo thesis I will show that foo bar is extremely important`

Comment: for the case of your example you can use [comment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) or [verbatim](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two idea.

1. If the file to be inputed does not change the whole strecture of document (if no  command like `\section` or `\global\textheight...`) one can do `\setbox0=\hbox{\let\def\gdef\input{file}}`
2. In cases like the Example here `\begin{ENV}...\end{ENV}` the best is to use
   [comment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) or [verbatim](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) packages

For example

```
\let\ENV=\comment
\let\endENV=\endcomment
```

Comment: I like the idea of selectively enable single parts of the included files with comment markers instead of trying to enable just the macros without displaying anything. Approved ;)